# Is the de Rham complex a free (commutative?) differential graded algebra?

Tags: abstract-algebra, differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, differential-forms

A differential graded algebra (dg-algebra) is a monoid object in the category of chain complexes with respect to the usual tensor product of complexes. A (graded) commutative dg-algebra is simply a commutative monoid object.

The de Rham complex for a smooth manifold is easily seen to be a commutative dg-algebra with respect to the wedge product.

I could have sworn that I saw somewhere that the de Rham complex is the free dg-algebra (or free commutative dg-algebra?) on some appropriate base category, i.e. left adjoint to a forgetful functor. I can't seem to find a reference for this, however.

With regards to my background I'm familiar with category theory and differential geometry, but my algebra is a bit weak.

Comment: Perhaps you're thinking of the cotangent complex in algebraic geometry.

Comment: Wedge product is not commutative. How does that fit into the story?

Comment: The first statement that comes to mind is that the de Rham complex should be freely generated as a commutative dg-algebra by its degree zero algebra (the algebra of smooth functions), but this is not actually true (see [this answer on MO](http://mathoverflow.net/a/9723/75), for instance).

Comment: @AmitaiYuval It's *graded* commutative: $\alpha \wedge \beta = (-1)^{|\alpha| |\beta|} \beta \wedge \alpha$ for homogeneous elements.

Comment: I think, but I haven't thought it out much, that the de Rham dga is the free skew-commutative graded $C^\infty(M)$-dga with $\Omega^1(M)$ in degree 1. Doesn't one deduce this from proposition 2.6 (page 57) in "Elements of noncommutative geometry" by Varilly et al.? One avoids problems of the kind pointed by Eric Wofsey by actually starting from the 1-forms.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is true that the algebraic de Rham complex is left adjoint to the forgetful functor from DGAs to $R$-algebras.

---

More precisely:
$\newcommand{\dgAlg}{\mathrm{dgAlg}}
\newcommand{\Alg}{\mathrm{Alg}}\newcommand{\Hom}{\mathrm{Hom}}$

**Proposition 1.** *We have an adjunction*

[image: adjunction]

*where*

1. *$\Omega^\bullet_{(-)/A}$ is the exterior algebra of the module of Kähler differentials of an $A$-algebra $A\longrightarrow(-)$, and*
2. *$忘\colon\dgAlg_A\longrightarrow\Alg_A$ is the forgetful functor sending a DGA $(D^\bullet,d^\bullet,\mu^{\bullet,\bullet})$ to the $A$-algebra $(D^0,\mu^{0,0})$.*

In other words, the algebraic de Rham complex is the *free differential graded algebra*.

---

Now, for the proof.

**Lemma 1** (*Universal Property of the $p$th Exterior Power*). Let $R$ be a ring and $M$ be an $R$-module. The pair $(\bigwedge^{p}M,p)$ where $p\colon M^{\otimes p}\twoheadrightarrow\bigwedge^{p}M$ is the natural projection satisfies the following universal property:

- Given another pair $(N,f)$ where $N$ is an $R$-module and $f\colon M^{\otimes k}\longrightarrow N$ is an alternating $R$-linear morphism of $R$-modules, there exists a unique morphism $\bigwedge^{p}M\dashrightarrow N$ of $R$-modules such that the diagram

[image]

commutes.

*Proof of Proposition 1.* We proceed by showing that we have a functorial isomorphism
$$\Hom_{\dgAlg_A}(\Omega^\bullet_{B/A},D^\bullet)\cong\Hom_{\Alg_A}(B,D^0)$$
for each $A$_algebra $B$ and each differential graded algebra $(D^\bullet,d^\bullet,\mu^{\bullet,\bullet})$.

Firstly, given a morphism $f^\bullet\colon\Omega^\bullet_{B/A}\longrightarrow D^\bullet$ of differential graded algebras, we get a morphism $f^0\colon B\longrightarrow D^0$ of $A$-algebras given as the $0$th component of $f^\bullet$.

Conversely, let $f\colon B\longrightarrow D^0$ be a morphism of $A$-algebras and consider the diagram

[image]

We claim that there exists a unique morphism $f^\bullet\colon\Omega^\bullet_{B/A}\longrightarrow D^\bullet$ of differential graded algebras such that $f^0=f$. This we prove via universal properties:

*The Degree $1$ Case.* Consider the diagram

[image],

note that $d\circ f$ is a $B$-derivation into $D^1$, and apply the universal property of the module of Kähler differentials (see [here](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00RO)) to get a unique map $\Omega_{B/A}^1\dashrightarrow D^1$ making the diagram

[image]

commute. This gives the degree $1$ component of our desired map $f^\bullet$ and shows the first square of the diagram given in the second picture of this answer to be commutative.

*The Degree $p$ Case.* Write $\Omega_{B/A}^1\otimes_A\cdots\otimes_A\Omega_{B/A}^1$ for the $p$th tensor product of $\Omega_{B/A}^1$ and consider the morphism
$$f^1\otimes_A\cdots\otimes_Af^1\colon\Omega_{B/A}^1\otimes_A\cdots\otimes_A\Omega_{B/A}^1\longrightarrow D^1\otimes_A\cdots\otimes_AD^1.$$
By functoriality of the $p$th exterior power, there is a unique morphism from $\Omega_{B/A}^p$ to $\bigwedge^pD^1$ such that the diagram

[image]

commutes. The multiplication maps $\mu^{p,q}\colon D^p\times D^q\longrightarrow D^{p+q}$ assemble into a unique multilinear map
$$(D^1)^p\longrightarrow D^p,$$
(the uniqueness of $\mu$ follows from the compatibility of the $\mu^{p,q}$'s) which corresponds, by the universal property of tensor products (i.e. that $R$-multilinear maps from $M^p$ correspond to $R$-linear maps from $M^{\otimes p}$), to a unique linear map
$$\mu\colon D^1\otimes_A\cdots\otimes_A D^1\longrightarrow D^p.$$
Moreover, the graded Leibniz rule for the $\mu^{n,m}$'s implies that $\mu$ is alternating. Consider now the diagram

[image]

By the universal property of the $p$th exterior power (Lemma 1), there exists a unique map $\bigwedge^{p}D^1\dashrightarrow D^{p}$ making the diagram

[image]

commute. Our desired $p$th component $f^p$ of $f^\bullet$ is then the composition of the vertical rightmost morphisms in this last diagram.

Thus we get a unique morphism $f^\bullet$ such that $f^0=f$. Since the constructions given here were done via universal properties, it is clear that they are inverse and functorial. This finishes the proof.

Comment: One reference where this adjunction is mentioned is page 63 of [J. I. Burgos Gil, The regulators of Beilinson and Borel. CRM Monograph Series, 15. American Mathematical Society, Providence, RI, 2002.](https://www.icmat.es/miembros/burgos/files/brbr.pdf)